# Redirect all urls to https except parked and sub domain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I installed an ssl on a website, and need to redirect all pages to https. I'm having some issues:

1 - I have a parked domain example.com that I'd like to redirect to example.net (main domain), matching any url, like example.com/image1.jpg to example.net/image1.jpg whether it includes www or not.

2 - I would also like to exclude a domain, test.com that points to test.example2.net (so actually a sub domain) from the https redirect.

I got this to work previously, found some codes here on stack overflow, but my final code was very long with more redirects than needed, and I assume it doesn't have to be.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The code below works great for all example.net urls.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
#exclude test.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !test\.com [NC]
#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @starkeen . Is there a way to not force the www, like the code I had above?

Comment: @rise If you dont want www in the url..just remove it from the destination.

Comment: Thanks again. I understand that. What I actually wanted was to leave as it is, so if the user comes from www, serve www, if not, then just https://example.com

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!